# Firebase data exchange in real time database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I was creating a simple sign up application that will register user information like name, email, unique id and password. But while storing it in real time database in firebase the details get exchanged that means if I am writing you321 in id and 123 in password then in database it is showing password : you321 and id : 123 I don't know what is the problem why it is exchanging here is the code of my Main.kt file-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var database : DatabaseReference

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val signUpButton=findViewById<Button>(R.id.signUp)
        val enterName=findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.editName)
        val enterMail=findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.editMail)
        val enterPass=findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.editpass)
        val enterId=findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.editID)

        signUpButton.setOnClickListener {
            val Name=enterName.text.toString()
            val email=enterMail.text.toString()
            val Id=enterId.text.toString()
            val password=enterPass.text.toString()

            val user=User(Name,email,Id,password)
            database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
            database.child(Id).setValue(user).addOnSuccessListener {
                enterName.text?.clear()
                enterMail.text?.clear()
                enterId.text?.clear()
                enterPass.text?.clear()
                Toast.makeText(this,"User Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }.addOnSuccessListener {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

User.kt file -

```
package com.example.registerexample

data class User(val name: String, val email:String , val id:String, val password:String){

}
```

Comment: The code looks fine. Are you sure, that you are entering id and password in right edit texts? Maybe you can print a log statement for these values from your user class once you created a user. It will help in identifying which part of code has error.

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: Not yet @AlexMamo

Comment: Have you tried to log the value of `Name`, `email`, `Id`, and `password` right before creating the object? What are the exact values?

Comment: How to do that, I am beginner don't know how to check the log value. @AlexMamo